# VBA Code to Allow Group / Ungroup in a Protected Workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the code below to protect and save the workbook automatically upon closing. However, this code isn't allowing me to use the group / ungroup feature when I re-open the workbook. Can I edit this code to allow the group / ungroup?

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

    ws.Protect Password:="your password", UserInterfaceOnly:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True
    ws.EnableOutlining = True

Next ws
ThisWorkbook.Protect "your password", True

ThisWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

I tried using the code below to allow the Group/Ungroup on opening, but it doesn't work the way I intended. I had to insert a button into the worksheet. The code does work with the use of a button. I was hoping for one automatic code to solve the group/ungroup problem which doesn't use a button.

```
Sub Workbook_Open()
For Each ws In Sheets
   With ws
       .Unprotect Password:="your password"
       .Protect Password:="your password", UserInterfaceOnly:=True
       .EnableOutlining = True
    End With
Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: What happens if you tie the code to a `Workbook_Open` event instead of using a button?

Comment: I still get a message saying I can't use the command (group/ungroup) on a protected sheet. The code only works when tied to a button inside the sheet.

Comment: How can that be since it looks through the sheets in the workbook (`For Each ws In Sheets`)?

Comment: I am getting the same command message repeatedly, across different workbooks, when using the Workbook_Open() code with the Workbook_BeforeClose macro.If I use the Workbook_Open() only, I don't have to use a button. The Workbook_Open() works, but only by itself. I need the workbook to automatically protect and save upon closing, and allow group/ungroup. I am looking for one macro to do these 3 things, but haven't found a working solution yet.

Comment: Try: `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets`

Comment: I added "ThisWorkbook.Worksheets" instead of "For Each ws In Sheets", however, I still can't use group/ungroup. Thank you for the suggestion though.